# How to handle facebook login with multiple targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

Here is my setup:

I have quite a few targets to run an app on the white-label method.

So each target has its own Info.plist, icons, names, etc.

The thing is that I want to have one login system only with facebook. So they all point to the same facebook app.

The problem: sometimes, when I login on app A using facebook, the facebook app open the app B.

I have all setup following the facebook guide with all bundle ids registered on facebook app, etc.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: You are using different Bundle Identifiers for each target correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by forcing facebook login behavior to stay on a webview.

loginBehavior = `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`

This way the users never leaver the app, so there is no chance of returning on a scheme opening the wrong app.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I have the same issue. Can you please provide more information on how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry @johnny that was 2 years ago and I don't have that project anymore. I remeber having to pop the webview window using `loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb `, because the other type would return the same schema everytime.